# url break when I want to using the password change from in crispy form in django

Tags: django-forms

When I want to use the password change form in UserChangeForm,after clicking the password change form button from the bottom rightside the url patterns( http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/changeprofile/)[befor click] make change and become like that (http://127.0.0.1:8000/4/password/)[after click].Here 4 is not fixed.This value is changed based on the user.Please help me to give a solution.How can I fix it?

I don't have any idea.